# How to update an associate table without updating the entity classes

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Let's say I have a bidirectional @many_to_Many relationship between two entity classes Person and Address.

In my case, the associative table Person_Address is not populated when the table Person and Address were populated. If I have a few entries already in  Person and Address table, then I need to add associative record into Person and Address, how to do this in JPA and Hibernate?

```
Person
1 John
2 Mary
3 Kate

Address
1 The 2nd Street
2 The 3rd Street
```

Now I have a method to add an association between "John" and "The 2nd Street", how to do this?

```
public void associate(Person person, Address address) {
   log.info("Associating ..." );

   entityManager.persist(???); // there is no explicit PersonAddress enitty
}
```

Is this a common scenario for associative table?

Comment: Where are the CLASSES? what is the relation between those CLASSES? if you dont have an object for it you dont update it. Update your objects fields. You are using an O-O programming language after all ...

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in JPA without updating the entity classes, it's not how JPA works.  The link table is there to support the entities and is not an entity itself by default so can not be updated in isolation.

If you need to update the link table without updating the entities (which to be honest seems a little strange to me!), you can drop down into native SQL:

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("update ...");
q.executeUpdate()
```

Your best approach however is to allow JPA to manage this relationship with the correct cascade properties set.  Then it becomes a simple case of:

```
person.getAddresses().add(address);
address.getPeople().add(person);
entityManager.persist(person);
```

Comment: Are there applications where the links (associations) are unknown when the entity tables are populated? How to model this in relational database? For example, two groups of people may become friends in the future. Whenever two persons from each group become a friend, a record needs to be added to the link table. Shouldn't this be modeled as a @many_to_many relationship in JPA? Or there are better options?

Comment: This is a very common use-case for JPA, it handles it very well with many-to-many relationships. It's a simple case of adding each entity to opposite collection and then saving the entities. JPA then creates an entry in the link table for you. Bypassing JPA is obviously possible, I don't see what benefit this gives though...

Comment: My question is, how to handle the case of "adding entities first, then later on adding links alone in the link table in JPA, without updating the entity class". i.e. "John" and "Mary" are in two tables Male and Female. The link table Friend is initially empty when the other two tables are populated. Some day I need to add a link between "John" and "Mary" in the Friend table. How do deal with this in JPA? That's my original question.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to create one more entity PersonAdress mapped to association table and saved it in you method..